# Load product template based on product id's

Tags: templates, opencart

I have around 20 or so products that need to load a specific product template, while all of the others load the default. Here's the code I have so far. I can't figure out how to incorporate multiple product id's. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if ($this->request->get['product_id'] == 200000864) {
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/customproduct.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/customproduct.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = '/template/product/customproduct.tpl';
    }
} else {
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = '/template/product/customproduct.tpl';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard coding this is really not a good idea. You would be better using something [like this extension](http://mos.so/8056)

Comment: Use code formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, I don't want to pay $50 for an extension. There's no way of hard coding it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> Opencart 2.0

From

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl')) {
                $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl', $data));
            } else {
                $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/product/product.tpl', $data));
            }
```

To

```
 switch ($this->request->get['product_id']) {
    case 1:
      $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/product/product1.tpl', $data));
        break;
    case 2:
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/product/product2.tpl', $data));
        break;

      //...
      //...
      //...
    case 200000864:
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/product/product200000864.tpl', $data));
        break;
    default:
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl', $data));
    }
```

You want this or something else

Comment: I'm a little confused as to where the product ID's should go. My apologies. I'm not very familiar with PHP.

Comment: Product id goes in " case <product_id>:"       and custom template will be in that case statement                             Tell me if u don't understand